# Fetching data with Arduino ESP82266 from Heroku Python App

Tags: python, api, heroku, https, arduino

I am new in Arduino with the Esp8266 and wanted to build a very simple project in which I have a Heroku App. Then an Arduino ESP8266 calls an API on this Web-App and reads the data.
My API is working without any problems:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)    

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return str(datetime.utcnow())


@app.route('/api', methods=['GET'])
def api():
    return jsonify({"time":str(datetime.utcnow())})
```

Now i want to read the data from this API on an Arduino. I don't know how to do that the right way so that's my main problem. Could anybody show me an example?
What i did so far was an very simple Arduino Code based on the HTTPRequests Example in the ESP8266 library. I didn't change anything besides my wifi credentials and the host and the url and the thumprint. This is the GET-Requests:

url=/api
host=https://wbot0707.herokuapp.com/api

```
client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

The output i get in the Serial Monitor is:

```
09:48:41.982 -> WiFi connected
09:48:41.982 -> IP address: 
09:48:41.982 -> 192.168.178.46
09:48:41.982 -> connecting to https://wbot0707.herokuapp.com
09:48:41.982 -> Using fingerprint '08:3B:71:72:02:43:6E:CA:ED:42:86:93:BA:7E:DF:81:C4:BC:62:30'
09:48:43.424 -> requesting URL: /api/
09:48:43.543 -> request sent
09:48:43.543 -> headers received
09:48:48.560 -> esp8266/Arduino CI has failed
09:48:48.560 -> reply was:
09:48:48.560 -> ==========
09:48:48.560 -> -1
09:48:48.560 -> ==========
09:48:48.560 -> closing connection
```

Thanks for anykind of help! And any suggtions to my code or my question (my first one ever ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
   BasicHTTPSClientNofingerprint.ino

   1.03.2019

*/

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>
// Fingerprint for demo URL, expires on June 2, 2019, needs to be updated well before this date
// const uint8_t fingerprint[20] = {0x5A, 0xCF, 0xFE, 0xF0, 0xF1, 0xA6, 0xF4, 0x5F, 0xD2, 0x11, 0x11, 0xC6, 0x1D, 0x2F, 0x0E, 0xBC, 0x39, 0x8D, 0x50, 0xE0};

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("SSID", "PW");
}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);

    //client->setFingerprint(fingerprint);
    client->setInsecure();

    HTTPClient https;

    Serial.print("[HTTPS] begin...\n");
    if (https.begin(*client, "https://domain.herokuapp.com/api")) {  // HTTPS

      Serial.print("[HTTPS] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = https.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = https.getString();
          Serial.println(payload);
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      https.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTPS] Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Wait 10s before next round...");
  delay(10000);
}
```